# Combining flex with position:fixed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to show a modal dialog but I am struggling with the combination of a flex layout and the dialog with a fixed positioning. The header and footer need to be fixed in height; the content section has an overflow with scrollbars. Reason why I chose the flex layout here is that the header could be hidden or vary in height, in that case I want the content to take all the available height.

What happens though, if I have the modal dialog with a position:relative (md-modal) everything works perfect.

Once I change to position:fixed on md-modal everything breaks. I am not seeing the root cause of what is causing this. Am I hitting a specification issue here?

I enclosed the situation in a 600/400 wrapper just for visibility.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.md-modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border:1px solid green;
    z-index: 2000;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

}
.md-show {
    visibility: visible;
}
.md-content {
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.md-effect-1 .md-content {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-show.md-effect-1 .md-content {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y:auto;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('dialog').classList.add('md-show')">test</a>

<div style="width:600px;height:400px">
<div class="md-modal md-effect-1 center" id="dialog">
    <div class="md-content">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="row header">
            <p><b>header</b>
              <br />
              <br />(sized to content)</p>
          </div>
          <div class="row content">
            <p>
              <b>content</b><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p>
              <p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p>
              (fills remaining space)
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="row footer">
            <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using any particular css library? To me looks centered and fine i guess (?) when position: fixed, and cut too much on the left when position: relative..

Comment: No this is just vanilla stuff, I extracted the relevant pieces from a pretty large codebase trying to isolate the issue I had.

Comment: So this is how you see it in your project? http://jsfiddle.net/0fu97z3j/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`position:fixed`, just like `position:absolute` takes the element **out of document flow**. It's pretty much like it doesn't exist, as far as its parent is concerned.

This means that it's rendered over the same space as elements that are *in* the document flow.

The difference between `absolute` and `fixed` is that absolute positioned elements are being positioned and sized relative to their closest positioned parent, while `fixed` ones are positioned and sized relative to their closest viewport.

Which means you want to: use `position:fixed` on a modal container, which should have the size of the viewport. This container is invisible (transparent) and contains the actual modal. You can use the centering technique of choice, but I suggest using

```
.modal-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I strongly advise against using absolute centering methods, such as `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`, as they fail miserably when the modal results in being taller than the viewport (you lose the ability to access the top).

That said, here's a very basic modal example:

```js
document.querySelector('#showModal').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.modal-container').classList.add('open');
})
document.querySelector('#hideModal').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('.modal-container').classList.remove('open');
})
```

```css
.modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.modal-background {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.42);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.modal {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  width: 900px;
  min-height: 80vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#hideModal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: 1em;
}
.open.modal-container {
  display: flex;
}
.modal > * {
  flex-grow: 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
.modal-body {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.modal-head, .modal-footer {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 1rem;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .modal {
     width: 600px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .modal {
     width: 90vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal">
    <a id="hideModal" href>Hide modal</a>
    <div class="modal-head">
      
      <h1>Modal title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      This is the modal body
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      This is the modal footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="showModal">Show modal</button>
```

Most people choose to use an already well rounded and well tested modal plugin. Also, most popular frameworks roll with their own modal already defined and ready to use.

Of course, building your own gives complete freedom over opening and closing animations and any of its reusable features.

---

Here's a quick-fix for your markup:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.md-modal {
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
  z-index: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.35);
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.md-show {
  visibility: visible;
}

.md-content {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5vw auto;
  width: 90vw;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 10vw);
  display: flex;
}

.md-content>* {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.md-effect-1 .md-content {
  transform: scale(0.7);
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-show.md-effect-1 .md-content {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}

.md-content .box .content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('dialog').classList.add('md-show')">test</a>

<div class="md-modal md-effect-1 center" id="dialog">
  <div class="md-content">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="row header">
        <p><b>header</b>
          <br />
          <br />(sized to content)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row content">
        <p>
          <b>content</b>
          <p>line</p>
          <p>line</p>
          <p>line</p>
          <p>line</p>
          <p>line</p>
          <p>line</p>
          (fills remaining space)
      </div>
      <div class="row footer">
        <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Makes sense. For some of the existing flex implementation I had those wrapped inside a relative dom element. In this case position:fixed is flexbox cryptonite.

Comment: I kind of fixed your modal. If you need something more reliable and/or flexible, IMHO, SO is not the place. You either hire a specialist or go with well tested libraries/plugins. Happy coding!

Comment: Clearly was hitting the specs here. Thanks for the support, much appreciated. Have to adapt your ideas; the transform translate was related to the fact that there are multiple